# Math Olympiad Prime Number Question

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math

> If $p$, $q$ and $r$ are prime numbers such that their product is $19$
>   times their sum, find $p^2$ + $q^2$ + $r^2$.

I came across this question in a Math Olympiad Competition and had no idea how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you tell which Math Olympiad Competition is this. You have posted some very good questions and all of them according to you are from this Math Olympiad.

Comment: This Math Olympiad is SMO(Junior) 2014

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One of the primes must be $19$, so WLOG $r=19$. Then $(p-1)(q-1)=20$. There aren't too many ways to factorise $20$...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you explain why one of the primes must be 19?

Comment: @thanby As p, q, r are prime numbers, their product will only have p, q, r and 1 as divisors. Hence, one of them must be 19.

Comment: How did you know $(p-1)(q-1)=20$?

Comment: because pq - p - q = 19 & (p-1)(q-1) = pq - p - q + 1

Comment: @MD-Tech I guess I'm a dunce, but I don't know where $pq-p-q=19$ comes from. EDIT: Nevermind! I worked it out, thank you

Comment: r = 19 therefore 19pq = 19(p + q + 19) edit: was writing during your edit

Comment: @fedorqui You forgot $pq, qr, rp, pqr$.  Probably you mean to say that $p, q, r$ are the only *prime* divisors.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on [Ivan Loh's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/821413/79601):

> If $p$, $q$ and $r$ are prime numbers such that their product is $19$ times their sum, find $p^2$ + $q^2$ + $r^2$.

This expression can be written as:
$pqr=19(p+q+r)$

As p, q, r are prime numbers, its product will just have p, q and r as prime divisors. Hence, one of them must be 19. Say $r=19$. Then, we have:

$pq19 = 19(p+q+19)$

$pq = p+q+19$

$pq-p-q = 19$ (*)

On the other hand, we always have the expression:
$(p-1)(q-1) = pq-p-q+1$

which is equivalent to:

$(p-1)(q-1)-1 = pq-p-q$

Joining with (*)

$(p-1)(q-1)-1 = 19$

$(p-1)(q-1) = 20$

20 can be factorised in:
$20=2*2*5$

in blocks of two:

$20=4 * 5$

or

$20=2 * 10$

or

$20=1 * 20$

so we have to options:

#### First

$p-1=4 -> p=5$

$q-1=5 -> q=6$

This cannot happen, because $p$, $q$, $r$ have to be prime and $p=6$ is not.

#### Second

$p-1=1 -> p=2$

$q-1=20 -> q=21$

This cannot happen, because $p$, $q$, $r$ have to be prime and $q=21$ is not.

#### Third

$p-1=2 -> p=3$

$q-1=10 -> q=11$

Both $p=3$ and $q=11$ are prime numbers, so we can go ahead.
In such case,

$p^2 + q^2 + r^2 = 3^2 + 11^2 + 19^2 = 9 + 121 + 361 = 491$

Comment: There are other factorisations of 20 which need to be taken into account: 1*20, -1 * -20, etc. Obviously they don't result in solutions, but they should be acknowledged.